# Create content type by code. New Form is empty

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to connect a content type by code, (dont ask why), lol. The feature works fine, the new column is added fine to the views.

For some reason in the NEW or Edit form the new Field Source Name is not present. When I go to List Settings, Advanced, it says Manage Content Types= NO, but I set it to Yes on the code.

I am out of ideas.

```
 private static void RemoveProductListAndCreateProductAndSourceList(SPWeb currentWeb)
        {
            currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            #region Adds/Removes the product and source list
                if (currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList(SponsoringCommon.Constants.LISTNAMES_PRODUCT_NAME) != null)
                {
                    currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList(SponsoringCommon.Constants.LISTNAMES_PRODUCT_NAME).Delete();
                    currentWeb.Lists.Add(SponsoringCommon.Constants.LISTNAMES_PRODUCT_NAME, string.Empty, SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
                }


                if (currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList(SponsoringCommon.Constants.LISTNAMES_SOURCES_NAME) != null)
                {
                    currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList(SponsoringCommon.Constants.LISTNAMES_SOURCES_NAME).Delete();
                    currentWeb.Lists.Add(SponsoringCommon.Constants.LISTNAMES_SOURCES_NAME, string.Empty, SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
                }
                else
                {
                    currentWeb.Lists.Add(SponsoringCommon.Constants.LISTNAMES_SOURCES_NAME, string.Empty, SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
                }
            #endregion

            #region HIde the title columns
                SPList productList = currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList(SponsoringCommon.Constants.LISTNAMES_PRODUCT_NAME);
                SPField titleField = productList.Fields.GetField("Title");
                titleField.ShowInEditForm = false;
                titleField.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                titleField.ShowInNewForm = false;
                titleField.Update();

                SPList sourceList = currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList(SponsoringCommon.Constants.LISTNAMES_SOURCES_NAME);
                titleField = sourceList.Fields.GetField("Title");
                titleField.ShowInEditForm = false;
                titleField.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                titleField.ShowInNewForm = false;
                titleField.Update(); 
            #endregion

            #region Add Source content type if it doesnt exist.
                SPContentType sourceContentType = currentWeb.ContentTypes[SponsoringCommon.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_SOURCES_NAME];
                SPContentTypeId sourceContentTypeid = new SPContentTypeId(SponsoringCommon.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_SOURCE_ID);
                if (sourceContentType == null)
                {
                    sourceContentType = new SPContentType(sourceContentTypeid,
                                                            currentWeb.ContentTypes,
                                                            SponsoringCommon.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_SOURCES_NAME);
                    currentWeb.ContentTypes.Add(sourceContentType);
                } 
            #endregion

            #region Removes the link from the content type column called Product Name 
                SPContentType productCT = currentWeb.ContentTypes[SponsoringCommon.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_PRODUCT_NAME];   
                productCT.DeleteFieldRefFromContentType(currentWeb.Fields[SponsoringCommon.Constants.FIELDS_PRODUCT_NAMEOLD]);                
            #endregion

            #region New fields properties
                SPFieldCurrency amountField = (SPFieldCurrency)currentWeb.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(SponsoringCommon.Constants.FIELDS_PRICE_NAME);
                amountField.ShowInNewForm = true;
                amountField.ShowInEditForm = true;
                amountField.ShowInDisplayForm = true;

                string productFieldName = currentWeb.Fields.Add(SponsoringCommon.Constants.FIELDS_PRODUCT_NAMENEW, SPFieldType.Text, true);
                SPField productField = currentWeb.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(productFieldName);
                productField.Group = "$Resources:SPNLSponsoring,Field_NationaleLoterijSponsoringColumns_Group";
                string schemaXmlWithResourceTokens = productField.SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens;
                int startIndex = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf("\"", schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf("DisplayName=\"")) + 1;
                int endIndex = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf("\"", startIndex);
                int substringLength = endIndex - startIndex;
                string value = @"DisplayName=\" + schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.Substring(startIndex, substringLength);
                schemaXmlWithResourceTokens = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.Replace(value, @"DisplayName=\$Resources:SPNLSponsoring,Field_Product_Name");
                productField.SchemaXml = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens;
                productField.ShowInNewForm = true;
                productField.ShowInEditForm = true;
                productField.ShowInDisplayForm = true;

                SPFieldLink fieldLinkProductName = new SPFieldLink(productField);
                SPFieldLink fieldLinkPriceName = new SPFieldLink(amountField);
                productCT.FieldLinks.Add(fieldLinkProductName);
                productCT.FieldLinks.Reorder(new string[] {productField.InternalName,amountField.InternalName});  //Reorder fields in the content type
                productCT.Update(true);                 

                productList.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
                productList.ContentTypes.Add(productCT);
                SPContentTypeCollection currentOrder = productList.ContentTypes; 
                List<SPContentType> result = new List<SPContentType>(); 
                foreach (SPContentType ct in currentOrder) 
                {
                    if (ct.Name.Contains(SponsoringCommon.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_PRODUCT_NAME)) 
                    { 
                        result.Add(ct); 
                    } 
                } 
                productList.RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = result; 
                productList.RootFolder.Update();

            #endregion

            string sourceFieldName = currentWeb.Fields.Add(SponsoringCommon.Constants.FIELDS_SOURCE_NAME, SPFieldType.Text, true);
            SPField sourceField = currentWeb.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(sourceFieldName);
            sourceField.Group = "$Resources:SPNLSponsoring,Field_NationaleLoterijSponsoringColumns_Group";
            schemaXmlWithResourceTokens = sourceField.SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens;
            startIndex = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf("\"", schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf("DisplayName=\"")) + 1;
            endIndex = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf("\"", startIndex);
            substringLength = endIndex - startIndex;
            value = @"DisplayName=\" + schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.Substring(startIndex, substringLength);
            schemaXmlWithResourceTokens = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.Replace(value, @"DisplayName=\$Resources:SPNLSponsoring,Field_Source_Name");
            sourceField.SchemaXml = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens;
            sourceField.ShowInEditForm = true;
            sourceField.ShowInNewForm = true;
            sourceField.ShowInDisplayForm = true;

            SPFieldLink fieldLinkSourceName = new SPFieldLink(sourceField);
            sourceContentType.FieldLinks.Add(fieldLinkSourceName);
            sourceContentType.Update(true);

            sourceList.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
            sourceContentType.Update(true);

            sourceList.ContentTypes.Add(sourceContentType);              
            SPContentTypeCollection currentOrderSourceList = sourceList.ContentTypes;
            List<SPContentType> resultSourceList = new List<SPContentType>();
            foreach (SPContentType ct in currentOrderSourceList)
            {
                if (ct.Name.Contains(SponsoringCommon.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_SOURCES_NAME))
                {
                    resultSourceList.Add(ct);
                }
            }
            sourceList.RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = resultSourceList;
            sourceList.RootFolder.Update();                   

            #region Modify views.
                SPView vwAllItemsProductList = productList.GetSafeViewByName(SponsoringCommon.Constants.VIEWS_ALL_ITEMS);
                SPViewFieldCollection colvwAllItemsProductList = vwAllItemsProductList.ViewFields;
                if (vwAllItemsProductList.ViewFields.Exists("LinkTitle"))
                {
                    vwAllItemsProductList.ViewFields.Delete("LinkTitle");
                }
                colvwAllItemsProductList.Add(productField);
                colvwAllItemsProductList.Add(amountField);
                vwAllItemsProductList.Update();

                SPView vwAllItemsSourceList = sourceList.GetSafeViewByName(SponsoringCommon.Constants.VIEWS_ALL_ITEMS);
                SPViewFieldCollection colvwAllItemsSourceList = vwAllItemsSourceList.ViewFields;
                if (vwAllItemsSourceList.ViewFields.Exists("LinkTitle"))
                {
                    vwAllItemsSourceList.ViewFields.Delete("LinkTitle");
                }
                colvwAllItemsSourceList.Add(sourceField);
                vwAllItemsSourceList.Update(); 
            #endregion

            currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

        }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do it this way?!?!?....only joking :D......This maybe no help what so ever but should you not be calling sourceList.Update() also for sourceList.ContentTypesEnabled = true; 
to take effect?

Comment: I tried, but it wasnt the problem. :(

Comment: I edited the question and included the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when I was creating the content type, it was based on Document, instead of item, so I changed that part to this and it worked.

```
  SPContentType itemCtype = currentWeb.AvailableContentTypes[SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Item];
                SPContentType sourceContentType = new SPContentType(itemCtype, currentWeb.ContentTypes, SponsoringCommon.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_SOURCES_NAME);
                sourceContentType = currentWeb.ContentTypes.Add(sourceContentType);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sourceList.ContentTypesEnabled = true; 
sourceContentType.Update(true); 

//Update the sourceList here this before you add the CT 
sourceList.ContentTypes.Add(sourceContentType);
```